# Cannot Delete Entity by Long Id

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, google-cloud-datastore

I have this JUnit code:

```
@Test
public void test(){
  Entity e = new Entity(KeyFactory.createKey("Post", 1L))
  Key key = _ds.put(e); // _ds is native DatastoreService
  _ds.delete(KeyFactory.createKey("Post", 1L));
  Entity deleted = _ds.get(KeyFactory.createKey("Post", 1L));
  assertNull(deleted); // Not null, why?
}
```

What could be the problem that `Entity` cannot get deleted?

I have tried to use the `Key` (generated by the put) as Key to the:

```
_ds.delete(key); // won't delete also?
```

(Although what I really need to to find out why it won't delete by Long id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your test slightly (to compile) and it is working for me:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

public class StackoverflowTest {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    private final DatastoreService _ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    /**
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031142/cannot-delete-entity-by-long-id
     */
    @Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public void test28031142() throws EntityNotFoundException {
        Entity e = new Entity(KeyFactory.createKey("Post", 1L));
        Key key = _ds.put(e); // _ds is native DatastoreService
        _ds.delete(KeyFactory.createKey("Post", 1L));
        _ds.get(KeyFactory.createKey("Post", 1L));
    }
}
```

Comment: I showed above that your code is working. I don't know how you're initializing _ds though. You can modify the question with additional code if this answer doesn't help.